# C# XML Comments: How many <see ... /> references in XML comments are useful?

Tags: c#, xml, comments

In our company we write excessive Xml comments. A typical method is has to be documented like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether this <see cref="IScheduler"/> contains a specific <see cref="ISchedule"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="schedule">The <see cref="ISchedule"/> to locate in this <see cref="IScheduler"/>.</param>
/// <returns>
/// Returns <see langword="true"/> if <paramref name="schedule"/> is found in this <see cref="IScheduler"/>; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.
/// </returns>
bool Contains(ISchedule schedule);

/// <summary>
/// Removes and <see cref="IDisposable.Dispose"/>s the first occurrence of a specific <see cref="ISchedule"/>
/// from this <see cref="IScheduler"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="schedule">The <see cref="ISchedule"/> to remove from this <see cref="IScheduler"/>.</param>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">Is thrown when the parameter schedule is null.</exception>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Is thrown when the <see cref="ISchedule"/> is not found in this <see cref="IScheduler"/> or was of the wrong type.</exception>
void Remove(ISchedule schedule);
```

As you can see nearly every noun which can be referenced using a `<see cref>` tag.
I find this too much. Most of our code files are so blown up with such comments. Makes the comments section nearly unreadable.

What do you think? Do you like this kind of documentation in the code or not?

As usual I think there is no black / white answer to such a kind of question, that's why I made it wiki.

EDIT:
My question was not if the see-ref-tags itself are useful per default. It is clear that the generated links in the .chm file (or any other kind of generated docu) are very useful. My question was if it's is really useful to tag every occurrence of every "linkable" noun in the comments.
We use Sandcastle to generate the docu every night. Unfortunately it is very rarly used by other developers, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 13):

Personally, I think what you have is a bit overboard.

The purpose of the "see" references is to provide good linking between topics in the generated help documentation after parsing.

In your case, your business-specific libraries are referencing language items, ie:

```
<see langword="true"/>
```

I personally feel that hyperlinks to other related objects **in your library** is a very useful feature.  It makes reading the help much more usable for your users.

Hyperlinks to language elements is something that I feel should only exist inside the language help itself.  In the case of a third party library, this just "muddles" up the message by putting links everywhere.  This makes the good links less effective, since they get hidden in the mess.

I would suggest liberal use of linking to related classes in your library.  I would avoid adding hyperlinks to base library classes, except in specific instances where it is particularly useful for some reason (rare).  Linking to "true" and "IDisposable.Dispose", etc, doesn't really add a lot of value.

Trust your user to understand the base framework, but teach them about your library.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Makes sense to say that the consumer of my library should at least now the build-in language tokens. Good point.

Comment: Yeah - when I see docs that link to the BCL everywhere, it comes across as "preachy" to me.  Doing that just assumes that your user doesn't understand what they're doing.

Comment: Yes, that is why it's more preferable to use `<c>null</c>` to distinguish it as a keyword belonging to the coding language's syntax rather than using `"see"` references.

Comment: That last sentence is amazing.

Answer (score 6):

The point of all of those is that when something like Sandcastle is used to generate HTML or CHM docs for the library, that those docs get hyperlinked navigation between objects.  So the question then is, when you use MSDN do you find it useful to be able to click on a class name a have it navigate to the help for that class, or are you ok with copying it and pasting it into the search field?

Yes, it bloats the code (though comments can be collapsed), but if you actually ship documentation to others, it's pretty darned helpful.

Comment: It is also very useful when using ReSharper's "Quick Documentation" feature (Ctrl-Q oin my key mappings).

Answer (score 4):

When you're working with Visual Studio, then you can use the CR_Documentor plugin (it's free, you can get it [here](http://code.google.com/p/cr-documentor/)) for WYSiWYG-reading/writing your comments. It looks like generated help form Sandcastle or NDoc, but is rendered on the fly. 
It's really useful, and you don't have to care about the raw xml comments at all.

Answer (score 3):

As ctacke said, it's very useful for hyperlinking. However, if you're not actually shipping documentation, all that  tagging makes the documentation virtually impossible to read. In that case, the documentation is for the (edit: INTERNAL) developer, and if he or she can't read it, you're wasting your time.

As a rule, I tend to  the first reference to a type or member, and leave the rest unlinked. It leaves the comments pretty clean, and still provides meaningful linking.

Answer (score 1):

There is a particular reason for these sorts of comments: they can be used to generate documentation or to add extra information to autocomplete. I agree that they are overly verbose and difficult to read for most situations, but they are good to add to an interface which you are going to expose externally.

I would recommend using an editor which allows you to turn comments on and off.

Some languages allow you to store comments as metadata on variables and functions, which is a nice alternative.